# ASP.NET: GridView Back Color does not change on Custom Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the back color of a grid View Table in asp.net based on the status of a thread, the thread launches events from which the following program launches (debugged and ensured that it is being called):

```
protected void updateGridView(UpdateGridViewArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == "Complete")
    {
        this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].BackColor = Color.Green;
        this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (e.Status == "Error")
    {
        this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (e.Status == "Ongoing")
    {
        this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].ForeColor = Color.Black;

        if (e.Index > 5)
        {
            //DisplayJobs.Invoke(new Action(() => DisplayJobs.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Index - 5));
        }
    }

}
```

However, the gridview table does not change.

when i launch

```
this.dgv_Display.Rows[0].BackColor = Color.Green;
```

from a button click event, the said row changes color, please advise.

Event Trigger script:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CustomEvents
{
    public delegate void UpdateGridViewHandler(UpdateGridViewArgs e);

    public class UpdateGridViewArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Status;
        public int Index;
        public UpdateGridViewArgs(string status, int index)
        {
            this.Status = status;
            this.Index = index;
        }

    }
}
```

Calling the trigger:

```html
FleetMonitor.UpdateDataTable(new UpdateGridViewArgs("Ongoing", index));
```

Trigger Event handling setup:

```html
 public static event UpdateGridViewHandler _gridViewEventHandler;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfigFile.Initialize("C:/IIS/App_Data/FleetMonitor.config");
            Limits.Initialize();
            populateGridView();
            populate_cmb_Times();
            _gridViewEventHandler += new UpdateGridViewHandler(updateGridView);
        }
        
public static void UpdateDataTable(UpdateGridViewArgs e)
        {
            if (_gridViewEventHandler != null)
            {
                _gridViewEventHandler(e);
            }
        }
```

Trigger Event Handling:

```html
protected void updateGridView(UpdateGridViewArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == "Complete")
            {
                this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].BackColor = Color.Green;
                this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (e.Status == "Error")
            {
                this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].BackColor = Color.Red;
                this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (e.Status == "Ongoing")
            {
                this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                this.dgv_Display.Rows[e.Index].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                this.dgv_Display.UpdateRow(e.Index, false);
                if (e.Index > 5)
                {
                    //DisplayJobs.Invoke(new Action(() => DisplayJobs.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Index - 5));
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is the `updateGridView` being called? What even is `UpdateGridViewArgs`? That's not any standard component so it's either something you have written or it's an external library.

Comment: yes the updateGridView is being called, UpdateGridViewArgs contains the status string and row index which i set, each row backcolor color allocation codes have been invoked which i ensured through debugging

Comment: Make sure no other CSS override your setting

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: use web developer tool, for instance, if you are using chrome, press F12

Comment: How `updateGridView` method is being called?